# Restricting specific folder access to a user

Tags: command-line, chmod, user-management

I have three users. For one user I want to restrict access to some specific folders. When I tried to do this through Ubuntu GUI, it did not work. Can you please tell me some commands so that I can disable listing of that folder to a specific user?

I have read on the net that I have to create groups and then assign permission to these groups, but I don't want to create groups since I have just one user.

I have tried the following, but it did not work:

`sudo chmod 755 -R my_folder`

Please tell me any inputs you want from my side.

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to  create a new group.  Add users you want to be able to view the folder to the group.  Then change the permissions of the folder with `sudo chmod 750 -R [folder]`.  You have to logout and back in before group changes will take effect.  A more complicated option is to use [Access Control Lists](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Access_Control_Lists).

Comment: `chmod -R` is almost never a good idea. Now all _files_ below that folder are executable. Not exactly sensible.